Basic examples how to use solana web3.js version 2.x and above
a beginner typescript developer here. I tried to get started with the web3.js library on version 2. But all the documentation I can find is for version 1.95.5 or older. And literally nothing works as very basic elements have been re-worked. All the examples provided in the official V2 release are way above in complexity.
Examples what I want to do: check the balance of a tokenMint for an account address.
The biggest problem I have is to understand the new logic with the different API types. How would I use any of the GetTokenAccountsByOwnerApi or GetBalanceApi inside a typescript running on nodeJS?

For the part of your question that has to do with how to create an RPC connection in the first place, look here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/17810/75

thanks @steveluscher the RPC connection setup worked for me using the recently published quicknode guides, for example here: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/tooling/web3-2/transfer-sol#establish-connection-to-solana-cluster

There are two kinds of balances you might be interested in (demo).
Native Solana token balance
This is the token in which fees and account rent are denominated. Given an RPC instance, you can use the getBalance API to check the balance of any account using its address.
import { address } from '@solana/web3.js';

const { value: lamports } = await rpc
    .getBalance(address('dv1ZAGvdsz5hHLwWXsVnM94hWf1pjbKVau1QVkaMJ92'))
    .send();

SPL Token balance
The balance of an account for a token other than the native Solana token can be fetched using the getTokenAccountBalance API. The trick is to find the address of a user's token account given that you only know their address and the address of the mint you're interested in.
Consider the token USDC (USD Coin) whose mint account address is known:
import { address } from '@solana-program/web3.js';
import { findAssociatedTokenPda, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ADDRESS } from '@solana-program/token';

const USDC_MINT_ADDRESS = address('EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v');

// Derive the user's USDC token account given their wallet address
// and the address of the USDC mint account.
const [usdcTokenAccount] = await findAssociatedTokenPda({
    mint: USDC_MINT_ADDRESS,
    owner: address("9b5piuVV9RLy6LnrnYiMjnmLKy7V9cD8XTDtds6WQ7Ax"),
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ADDRESS,
});
const { value: { amount, decimals } } = await rpc
    .getTokenAccountBalance(usdcTokenAccount)
    .send();


Thanks a lot! Now I get how the new APIs are intended to be used :) Once I got the 15 reputation, I will upvote your reply.

It's your own question; is there not a checkmark to accept the answer somewhere?
